# Using pattern matching in an abstract class to call a method that depends on a type

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, abstract-class

I made some simplifications of my original code just to focus on the problem.

I have this set of classes:

```
abstract class A(n: String){
   def name = n
}

abstract class B[T](n: String) extends A(n){
   def printT(t: T) = println(t)
}

object B{
   def unapply[T](b: B[T]) = Some(b.name)
}

case class C extends B[Int]("integer")
```

Now I want to discover on a List of As what extends B and then use printT. Something like this:

```
val list = List(C)

list match{
   case b @ B(_) => b.printT(2) 
}
```

On the line `case b @ B(_) => b.printT(2)` I got:

```
found   : Int(2)
required: T where type T
case b @ B(_) => b.printT(2)
                              ^
```

Probly this problem would be solved if I could associate the T on the object that I want to use the T of the class. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

1) Case classes should be declared with a parameter list: `case class C()`

2) To instantiate a `C`, you need to write `C()`.  `List(C)` is a `List[C.type]` but `List(C())` is a `List[C]`, which is what you want.

3) `list match` doesn't make sense if your case is a `B`: `list` is a `List`, so it can *never* be a `B`.  Perhaps you meant `list foreach`, which will do the match on each element in the list?

Here's a corrected version of your code that prints `2` as expected.

```
case class C() extends B[Int]("integer")

val list = List(C())

list foreach {
  case b @ B(_) => b.printT(2)
}
```

Additionally, the `b @ B(_)` syntax looks a bit weird to me since there's no point in extracting `B` if you're not going to use its parts.  You could, instead, just match on the type:

```
list foreach {
  case b: B[Int] => b.printT(2)
}
```

Comment: Fixed all the problems. Some of them was disctraction when I was simplifying my code. Thanks :)